# tag-it - how to use preprocessTag method?

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I would like to use tag-it to make lables all uppercase.

```
$('#taglabel').tagit({
   availableTags: ['this','label1']
});
```

how do i join preprocessTag method with available tags?

should i use it

```
$('#taglabel').tagit({
 "preprocessTag", function(val) {
  if (!val) { return ''; }
  return val[0].toUpperCase() + val.slice(1, val.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is :

```
$("#tag-it".tagit({
  availableTags: ["...","..."],
  ...
 });
```

and then

```
// ensure all tags are capitalized
$("#tag-it").tagit("preprocessTag", function(val) {
   if (!val) { return ''; }
   return val[0].toUpperCase() + val.slice(1, val.length);
});
```

is the only way

**UPDATE**

you're syntax :

```
    $('#taglabel').tagit(  { <-- this curly brace is wrong
    "preprocessTag", function(val) {
      if (!val) { return ''; }
      return val[0].toUpperCase() + val.slice(1, val.length);
    });
```

Comment: I want the new tags added to be uppercases as well...hence want to use preprocessTags. Not sure how to use that?

Comment: when you use tagit, how to add available Tags and also use preprocessTag?  Is my question clear?

Comment: that does not work as preprocess is not event it is method call

Comment: Yeah i just noticed it, so you need to call first available and then preprocess

Comment: Use my syntax ,which is taken from the official documentation, not yours. You're using "{" which is for option, not for method

Comment: neither of them works. that is tag prepopulates but are NOT upper cased.

Comment: i used your syntax correct one, but as i mentioned it does nto upper case the tags.Also is $("#tag-it".tagit({ purposely written that way....shouldnt it be $(("#tag-it").tagit({

Comment: maybe because availableTags does not call createTag.. try to manually create them and check out, just for curiosity..